# How to create a new object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Why is this not working??

```
    var sheep = function(options){
        this.options = {sizes: 100,
                        eat: 100,
                 colors: 'white', 
                 running: function () {
                     return this.sizes + this.eat;
                 }
          }
    };

    var blacksheep = new sheep({colors:'black'});       

    alert('blackcsheep color is ' + blacksheep.colors);//error undefined
    alert('blackcsheep color is ' + blacksheep.options.colors);// it return white
    alert('blackcsheep running is ' + blacksheep.running());//error
```

Comment: `sheep` is already an object. I think reading about JavaScript basics would help you the most: [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide), especially [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: @FatDogMark: What do you want exactly. sheep is already an object.

Comment: but how do i make another black sheep base on the sheep? to inherit the properties of sheep

Comment: js is a prototype based language, so to say, so that your sheep can't be used as a class. you rather copy the sheep (this is not the real way you can do it in js but only the idea): blacksheep = sheep; blacksheep.color = 'black'; and you are done more or less.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: `blacksheep = sheep` would not create a copy of `sheep`, both variables just refer to the same object. This has nothing to do with prototypal inheritance.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, I am not fresh at js, wanted just to scatter the idea of "copying" and it's why I made the comment and not the answer! :) (pointed in the edited comment too now)

Comment: Now you changed your code and answers / comments might become invalid... why did you do that? It really looks like you should read some introduction again, because the code is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: though about having nothing to do with prototype: if you do a deep copy of an object and then modify the copy, you have used the original object de facto as a prototype; maybe it's not paradigmatic for js, but that's the concept of the prototype

Comment: @FelixKling are you addressing me? I've not changed the "code", just added the (this is not the real way you can do it in js but only the idea); if you've seen something different, it was just in your eyes.

Comment: @FatDogMark: I think you should look deeper into function expressions and function declarations.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: No, I was addressing the OP... and they changed their code again :-/

Comment: @FatDogMark: Please don't update your question with every iteration of your code. Most answers will become useless. Make comments on answers, try things and more importantly, read documentation! Blindly trying things, wondering why it does not work and then posting it here is not really fruitful.

Comment: uhmm sorry i know, but i just think i missed something and edited it again,I just want to do thing like blacksheep = new sheep({colors:'black',sizes=10});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax:

```
var sheep = {sizes:100, eat:100, colors:'white',running:function(){
        return this.sizes+this.eat;
        }
    };
```

is an object literal. It defines an instance of an object, but not the class that defines it. Therefore, there is no way to "new-up" another instance of the object.

Take a look at jQuery's `extend` functionality:

```
var blacksheep = {
}

$.extend(blacksheep, sheep, { color: black });
```

This will copy all the properties of `sheep` into `blacksheep`, then merge the third parameter into `blacksheep`, effectively achieving what you want.

Comment: $.extend is just convenience for me, alright I accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

To make another black sheep based on sheep, in this scenario you could do (using jQuery):

```
var blacksheep = $.extend(sheep, { color: 'black' });
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way without jQuery. Cloning objects is messy - an example with function Sheep() {...} should be used. Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript for cloning javascript objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sheep object like this.

```
 function Sheep(sizes,eat,colors){
    this.sizes = sizes;
    this.eat = eat;
    this.colors = colors;
    this.running = function (){
     return this.sizes+this.eat;
    }

    }
```

Alternatively you can write like this also

```
 function Sheep(sizes,eat,colors){
    this.sizes = sizes;
    this.eat = eat;
    this.colors = colors;        
    }
 sheep.prototype.running = function(){
 return this.sizes + this.eat;    
}
```

var sheep1 = new Sheep('100','100','white');

Answer (score 1):

```
var sheep = function(){
    this.sizes = 100;
    this.eat = 100;
    this.colors = 'white';
    this.running = function(){
        return this.sizers + this.eat;
    }
}
```

Comment: why would I need 'this' in all variables ... can't I just wrap my sheep object in a function and turn it into class?

Comment: var a = new sheep(); a now has property sizes... because of 'this'

Comment: 'this' is current sheep class. Read here what does it mean: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't declare objects in JavaScript in the same way as you do in strongly-typed languages.  You declare objects by using functions like this:

```
function sheep() {
    this.color = "white";
    this.size = 200;
    this.speed = 100;
    this.running = function () {
        return "the sheep is running!";
    };
}

var blacksheep = new sheep();

alert('sheep size is ' + blacksheep.size);
alert('sheep running is ' + blacksheep.running());​
```

---

Your new object does not work because you are creating a new object with a sub-object called `options`. `options` contains all of your methods. As such only the second of these three lines that you gave will give you the correct response:

```
alert('blackcsheep color is ' + blacksheep.colors);
alert('blackcsheep color is ' + blacksheep.options.colors); // Only this one correctly references `options`.
alert('blackcsheep running is ' + blacksheep.running());
```

Comment: I see some people make class dont need to this everything that put this.options{...} then he can create new object like blacksheep = new sheep({colors:'black',sizes=10}); , how to do that??

Comment: My first example shows how to do just that. When you call the function `new sheep()`, `this` refers to the new object that is being created. What `var blacksheep = new sheep()` does is apply all the properties referenced by `this` in the `sheep()` function to the variable `blacksheep`. As such you can then go on to reference as I did, `blacksheep.size`, `blacksheep.running()` and so forth. Try this out here: http://jsfiddle.net/SZQVn/

Answer (score 0):

in your case sheep is already an object you can not create object of an object.
you can directly use that object with property.

But i think you want something like this

> var sheep = {sizes:100, eat:100, colors:'white', running:function(){
>               return this.sizes+this.eat;
>               }
>           }; Object.defineProperty(sheep, 'colors', { value:    'black'
>                                                , writable: true });

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is prototype based not class based. It does not use classes and is also object orientated.

```
var whitesheep =new sheep("100","100","white","running");
var blacksheep =new sheep("100","100","black","running");
```

Comment: Did you try this out in browser console ? this will not work unless you define a function object and returns some kind of object which has its properties as the values passed.